# Problema com PHP no formulario para editar

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Gente, preciso de uma ajuda. Estou fazendo um trabalho em PHP, mas não consigo editar pelo form nem logar.
edita-usuario.php /

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "conexao.php";
    $id = $_GET['idusuario'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id={$id}";
    $usuario = $conn->query($sql);
    //print_r($cliente->fetch_assoc());  
    $dados = $usuario->fetch_assoc();
    //echo $dados['email'];
     $conn->close();
?>
    <?php include "include/header.php" ?>

  <h1>Edita Cliente</h1>
    <form method="get" action="atualizar-usuario.php" >

    <input type="hidden" name="id" size="15" 
            value="<?php echo $dados['id'];?>" /> 

        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" size="15" 
            value="<?php echo $dados['email'];?>" /> 
        <br/>

        <label>Senha</label>
        <input type="text" name="senha" size="15"  
            value="<?php echo $dados['senha'];?>" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Atualizar" />
    </form>
    <?php include "include/footer.php" ?>
```

atualizar-usuario.php

```
<?php include "conexao.php"; $id = $_POST['id']; $EmailUsuario = $_POST['email']; $SenhaUsuario = $_POST['senha']; $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET email='{$EmailUsuario}', senha='{$SenhaUsuario}' WHERE id={$id}"; if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "Atualizado com sucesso"; }else { echo "Error: " . $conn->error; } $conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: atualizar-usuario.php

<?php
   include "conexao.php";
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $EmailUsuario = $_POST['email'];
    $SenhaUsuario = $_POST['senha'];
 $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET email='{$EmailUsuario}', senha='{$SenhaUsuario}' WHERE id={$id}";  
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "Atualizado com sucesso";
 }else {
 echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
 }
 $conn->close();
?>

Comment: Coloque isso na sua pergunta e não nos comentários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você colocou o conteúdo do `atualizar-usuario.php` nos comentários ficou meio ruim de entender...

O que eu percebi é que você está enviando os dados por GET:

```
<form method="get" action="atualizar-usuario.php" >
```

Porém no atualizar-usuario.php você está esperando dados via POST.

Ajuste o formulário para enviar dados via POST ou ajuste o código PHP para receber dados via GET.

Solução 1:

```
<form method="POST" action="atualizar-usuario.php" >
```

Solução 2

```
<?php 
include "conexao.php"; 
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$EmailUsuario = $_GET['email']; 
$SenhaUsuario = $_GET['senha']; 
$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET email='{$EmailUsuario}', senha='{$SenhaUsuario}' WHERE id={$id}";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Atualizado com sucesso"; 
}else { 
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error; 
} 
$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Alguns links dobre MÉTODOS HTTP:
- MÉTODOS HTTP: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

- Mais sobre `$_POST` https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php
- Mais sobre `$_GET` https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php
- Tutorial explicando melhor sobre o uso do GET e POST http://www.devfuria.com.br/php/enviando-dados-via-get-post/

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!